# laravel: mas una vista de una misma tabla

Tags: php, laravel, rutas, vistas

Necesito, si es que se puede hacer, hacer mas de una vista, pero de la misma tabla. Es una tabla grande, con muchos campos.. la idea es en cada vista, mostrar los campos que necesita usar cada sector. Ejemplo tabla columnas 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8. Vista 1 usa columnas 1/2/3, vista dos usa columnas 4/5/6/7, etc... la tabal sería solo una; pero debo hacer dos controladores? o con el mismo controlador puedo hacer dos vistas/rutas diferentes?

Espero haber sido claro. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De una misma tabla o modelo puedes hacer los controladores y vistas que quieras. En tu caso puedes hacer dos rutas dentro del mismo controlador. Imagina que tu modelo es `Content`, en tu controlador `ContentController`:

```
public function contentRoute1()
{
   return view('content.route1', ['contents' => Content:all()];
}

public function contentRoute2()
{
   return view('content.route2', ['contents' => Content:all()];
}
```

En tu archivo de rutas:

```
...
Route::get("/content_route1", [ContentController::class, "contentRoute1"]);
Route::get("/content_route2", [ContentController::class, "contentRoute2"]);
```

Comment: Gracias Eric! me funcionó para crear otra vista; tendré q investiar sobre como usar dos o mas controladores de una misma tabla, ya que eso si que no pude lograrlo de momento. Saludos!

Comment: Puedes hacerlo igual sin problemas, separas los metodos `contentRoute1()` y `contentRoute2()` en dos controladores distintos y en el archivo de rutas cambias el controlador: `Route::get("/content_route2", [AnotherContentController::class, "contentRoute2"]);`